# Flutter: Can't run build from Xcode on iOS device after copying project to a different Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I copied a Flutter project folder to a different Mac. However, I can't build and run or build and archive the app within Xcode.

1. When I use "flutter run" during development, the app works perfectly in Simulator and on real iOS devices.
2. "flutter build ios" runs through without errors.
3. When I try to build and run on a real device within Xcode, it fails with several errors, stating missing header files and failed Command CompileSwift with a nonzero exit code (see screenshot).

[image: xcode screenshot of errors]

The exact same project builds and runds perfectly on the other computer.

On the new computer, I have tried

- removing Pods folder and podfile.lock
- removing Xcode derivedData folder
- removing CocoaPods cache folder in Library to re-download all pods
- flutter clean

Yet I keep running into the same issue and after trying for several hours, I'm running out of ideas. Did any of you have a similar issue and do you have an idea what might help?

Flutter doctor does not print any errors, current version Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I "solved" the issue by manually copying the Library/Caches/CocoaPods folder from Mac 1 to Mac 2. Building and running then works fine on Mac 2.

I don't consider this a solution, however, since this feels more like a hack than a proper solution. Deleting the cache should correctly re-download everything, so I'm still looking for the cause of the problem to future-proof the setup...

Comment: how were you updating cocoapods on the new mac?

Comment: I tried running pod install from within the /ios folder and flutter pub get.

Comment: And the problem has resurfaced just now. Rebooted the Mac this morning, tried to build and run a new build in Xcode, the same problem with the "not found" files, even though it worked yesterday...
I don't understand why it works perfectly with "flutter run", but when running from xcode, it doesn't work ..